# How to Downgrade iPhone application from Apple Store

Tags: iphone, ios

How to Downgrade iPhone application from Apple Store.

I have my one application in Apple Store Live with version 1.4 for some reason i need to downgrade to 1.3 and remove 1.4.

How can i do like this from apple developer portal OR http://itunesconnect.apple.com/.

Cheers.

Comment: I don't think this is a programming question - You're better off asking at the Apple Developer forums.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible. Re-submit v1.3 of your app as v1.5.